# Visual Studio Watch Window Debugger Displaying Nothing

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, watch-window

I was working on my application today, and literally all of a sudden, my debugger just stopped working.

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013. Normally when I debug, I set the breakpoint, and hit f11 to step into, and watch the updated results in what I believe is the watch window. However now it is completely blank. Nothing displays at all.

The program compiles, runs and builds fine, and I have literally been over what seems like most quick fix solutions on the internet. Has anyone else ever had this problem?

EDIT:

Once a breakpoint is set, I can right click a variable and add to watch to debug, but this just isn't convenient. I assume then for some reason it has decided to not add everything to watch by default. Is this an option somewhere in VS?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out Visual Studio had decided not to watch anything in my code when debugging. All I had to do in the end was:

Start a debug, and wait for the breakpoint. Then go to:

Debug -> Windows -> Autos

And they returned!

Comment: can you please elaborate this :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, What I was missing was Debug > windows > Locals.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today in VS2022 Version 17.5.3 (64-bit) on Win11 Pro Version 22H2.
Closing and opening Debug -> Windows -> Autos, or Locals or Watch 1 didn't help, while Watch 2 was working.

I solved the problem after reading the hint from Justin Weiler for a similar problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-watch-and-quickwatch-do-not-work/49725):

"Restarting VS a few times will fix it temporarily."