# Watch in Debug is not showing anything

Tags: c, debugging

Well, I recently started learning C and wanted to debug my C program but I came across a random issue. When I started debug, the watch window stayed blank and didn't show anything. I don't understand why this is happening as I have set breakpoints in code and everything else.

Thank you :)

I followed a lot of tutorials and some stackoverflow questions like [Visual Studio Watch Window Debugger Displaying Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721751/visual-studio-watch-window-debugger-displaying-nothing)
but couldn't find any solution :<

Comment: Use the Locals window if you want to see anything.  The Watch window requires adding watches: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2022#observe-variables-with-a-watch-window

Comment: You should tag it with your whatever version of visual studio you are using.

Comment: 1.77.0 is my VS code version